# Retrieving user data from Parse "_User" class using "ObjectId"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

i am trying to retrive a user's data to get the user info from the `_User` class using the object id. i used this :

```
var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
func loadData() {
    data.removeAllObjects()

    var profileQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        profileQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userId, block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.data.addObject(objects!)
            }
        })
    println(userId) // this is the userId as String.
    println(self.data)  ********* // empty array.
}
```

i am getting an empty array `data` here.. I've tried this also but same thing's happening here too. :

```
 var profileQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        profileQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: userId)
        profileQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    self.data.addObject(object)   
                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Larcerax that's not essential to the question, as it's a parameter supplied to the query.

Comment: @pxlshpr, you aren't the OP so how do you know?

Comment: @Larcerax because I've used Parse extensively before. You would need access to OP's Parse app to cross-reference if it exists (which is what I'm assuming you're going for).

Comment: @Larcerax but how would you check that by asking for its *value*?

Comment: Wow, sounds like we've clearly got different investments in this. I'll politely back out of this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" happens async! You need to put any logic pertaining to the data inside of the block.

```
var profileQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
profileQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userId, block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        self.data.addObject(objects!)
        println(self.data) //shouldn't be empty.
    }
})
```

Comment: I think the `userId` is pre-populated by OP and used to make the actual query—so it need not be inside the block, really. Just `self.data`.

Comment: Yeah, i misspoke there. Fixed.

Comment: Very nice. Akshay Kheveria, It's also worth noting the reason why self.data returns nil is because the actual method executes ___and completes___ way before the item is retrieved, because it's being retrieved separately on a different thread (in the background), inside a block. This is a common issue with new Parse devs. Spread the word. +1 @AlexKoren for the async reference

Comment: hi.. Thanks .. It worked.. I've got one more problem here.. i'm trying this: `fullName.text = self.data["fullName"] as! String` to get the `fullName` but there i get an error : `cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'String?'` how can i get the `fullName` from `data` now..

Comment: You should ask another question, but at first glance it's because your data object is an array. So you'd have to get the first item of the array (the user) and then ask for the "fullName" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside why you're using an `NSMutableArray` for a singular `PFUser` object—you're basically expecting to see `self.data` populated in the wrong location. The user would be added to it (assuming a successful retrieval), *inside* the closure. So do something like:

```
var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
func loadData() {
    data.removeAllObjects()

    var profileQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    profileQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userId, block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.data.addObject(objects!)
            println(self.data)  //...shouldn't be empty here
        } else {
            println("Error retrieving user: \(error.description")
        }
    })
}
```